# GCC (NOLOAD)-directive cause wrong memory mapping

Tags: c, gcc, memory, attributes, ld

I am working with GCC(MIPS).
Here are the relevant parts from my .ld file.

```
MEMORY
{
   MEMORY_1                : ORIGIN = 0xB014D000,          N
   ....
   MEMORY_N                : ORIGIN = 0x9C00C800,          LENGTH = X*K
}
SECTIONS
{
   ....
 .my_section  ALIGN(32)           (NOLOAD)  : { } > MEMORY_1
   ....
}
```

Defenition of global buffer at the code:

```
static U32 __attribute__((section(".my_section"))) gBuffer[size];
```

I expected `gBuffer[]`address to be at `MEMORY_1`, however, its address is `0x9c0*****` i.e. at `MEMORY_N`.
Why? How can I fix it?

**EDIT:**
I discovered that after deleting the `NOLOAD` directive the buffer located at `MEMORY_1`.

> The (NOLOAD) directive will mark a section to not be loaded at run time. The linker will process the section normally, but will mark it so that a program loader will not load it into memory.

I need to use the (NOLOAD) directive here. What is the explanation for the described behavior?
How can I use NOLOAD without my buffer being moved to unexpected memory?

**EDIT2:**
The ld file will look like this(according to Matthias's suggestion):

```
_gBuffer_1 = address(MEMORY_1),
_gBuffer_2 = address(MEMORY_1) + _gBuffer_1_size,
_gbuffer_3 = address(MEMORY_1) + _gBuffer_1_size + _gBuffer_2_size.......
```

_gBuffer_i_size must be defined in the ld file.
I have many dozens of such buffers in my code and a lot of sections.
Now, every time someone wishes to add a new buffer or change existing one(delete it or change its size...) he must go through the ld file and recompute the addresses, that is why I find the suggested approach less easy to maintain. 
The original approach allowed to define buffers, easily locate it in every section the programmer wish and leave the rest of the work to the linker.The problem aroused after adding the `(NOLOAD)` directives.

Comment: Reverse the addresses ?

Comment: Did you put a `SECTION{` ... `}` around your section declarations?

Comment: @Matthias, yes I did.

Comment: Sometimes, the linker is a bit oversensitive regarding the grammar. Did you try `>MEMORY_1` (i.e. without the space)?

Comment: @Matthias. Tried, didn't help...

Comment: What exactly do you try to archive? Is the `static` array within a function or global? It seems you want to bind the array to a specific address (hw register?) Wouldn't be then a combination of `PROVIDE` and `extern` a better choice? You could avoid the non-portable gcc attributes.

Comment: @Matthias I wish to locate the buffer at a specific section in a specific memory. The buffer is global (in a source file).Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just ran into the same issue. Our work-around is adding an extra layer of indirection:

```
.my_section_noload ALIGN(32) (NOLOAD) :
{
  *(.my_section)
} > MEMORY_1
```

No idea why this works while using it directly doesn't.

Comment: .my_section is an input section, taken in this case from multiple .o files (that the "*" bit). On the other hand, ".my_section_noload" is an output section, generated by the linker when collating the input data. The output has a similar name to avoid confusion. Theoretically you could call it ".happiness" but a debugger might have a job figuring out what you meant....

Comment: ... By "similarly" I don't mean "exactly". If you generate function sections with -ffunction-sections in gcc, you will have lots of .text sections (.text.main, .text.function1, .text.init etc etc). These will be specified as input with `*(.text*)` and output as just `.text`. If the linker is asked to garbage collect, it will throw away input sections that are unreferenced.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid using gcc attributes at all. Simply provide the symbol in the linker file:

```
_gBuffer = 0xB014D000;
```

Then you can declare the buffer as extern:

```
extern U32 gBuffer[size];
```

Now, the linker should bind the extern declaration to the given address.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there another more maintainable way to achieve the same goal? I have a lot of buffers and a lot of section.Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Why is this approach less maintainable the the original one?

Comment: @Matthis, you may find my answer at EDIT2 at the original post, thanks.